# pwm 0-5v to 0-12v , what's wrong with this circuit

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, pwm, opto-isolator

What is wrong with this circuit.
I'm trying to control a 12v solenoid from a cnc board. At 1kHz and 10% pwm I get around 5v and 12v at 15%. Not 0-100% = 0-12v. I ended up with this circuit by looking at forums but can't find the original image anymore. I'm new into this and trying to learn.

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of C2? I cannot see any reason to place it there. U5 also.

Comment: Welcome! Do you require galvanic isolation?

Comment: thanks C2 is a bypass capacitor , maybe no need

Comment: @JCN It's connected between +12V and the output instead of +12V and ground, so the transistor is having to discharge it through U5 on every pulse. What you've probably done  there is taken a high speed optocoupler and turned it into a low speed optocoupler.

Comment: Have you read the 6N136 datasheet, particularly the test schematics?

Comment: thank you all for helping out !! @GodJihyo yes you totally right, it should be connected to ground. Will give it a try tomorrow .

Comment: @GodJihyo that solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the schematic C2 is connected between +12 V and the emitter of the opto-coupler, which is the output. When the opto-coupler transistor is off the capacitor charges through 10k resistor U7. When the transistor turns on it has to discharge C2 through 2.2k resistor U5. The RC time constants are long enough that it integrates the pulses, preventing the circuit from operating correctly.